# Is it possible to develop a Xamarin project on linux?

Tags: linux, xamarin

Can i develop a Xamarin application on Linux? I would need to develop mobile applications for Android and iOS.

Comment: at the moment, no.  Even if the IDE and tools were available on Linux, you would still need a Mac build server to build iOS apps.

Comment: It should be a must to write a comment if you down vote i think. Why the -1?

Comment: @Jason That's not a problem. I can make a Virtual Machine for that. But are there even tools to build a Xamarin application in linux?

Answer (score 0):

You can read this discussion in xamarin forum

https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/66118/xamarin-studio-for-linux

But for me, I would suggest, you use either Visual Studio for Windows or Visual Studio for Mac in Mac Machine. :) These IDEs are easy enough to use in order to build you xamarin application.